# SqlAlchemy returns wrong data for association table with association proxy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I defined a role / permission model using the following model structure:

```py
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    permissions = db.relationship("Permission", secondary=Role2Permission.__tablename__)

    @classmethod
    def find_by_id(cls, id):
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

class Role2Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'role_2_permission'

    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('roles.id'), primary_key=True)
    permission_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('permissions.id'), primary_key=True)
    bool_value = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

class Permission(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'permissions'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    action = db.Column(db.String(255))
    role2permission = db.relationship('Role2Permission', lazy='joined')
    bool_value = association_proxy('role2permission', 'bool_value')
```

When I fetch a role I want to have the permission value (`bool_value`) to be set via the association proxy coming from the association table. However using `cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()` (where `cls` is the `Role`) returns the wrong `bool_value`s for the queried role. I think the reason can be seen when looking at the generated SQL:

```sql
SELECT permissions.id                    AS permissions_id,
       permissions.action                AS permissions_action,
       role_2_permission_1.role_id       AS role_2_permission_1_role_id,
       role_2_permission_1.permission_id AS role_2_permission_1_permission_id,
       role_2_permission_1.bool_value    AS role_2_permission_1_bool_value
FROM role_2_permission,
     permissions
         LEFT OUTER JOIN role_2_permission AS role_2_permission_1 ON permissions.id = role_2_permission_1.permission_id
WHERE 1 = role_2_permission.role_id AND permissions.id = role_2_permission.permission_id
```

I think this is fetching too many rows because it's selecting from the permissions table instead of just joining it to the `role_2_permission` table but then for some reason joining `role_2_permission` again. Somehow flask / sqlalchemy is then reducing the returned rows in a bad way: It's not actually  so instead of the `bool_value`s that belong to e.g. role 1, it returns the `bool_value`s that belong to role 2.

How do I have to fix my model to get the correct permission data when querying the role?

Comment: could you please clarify what exactly is the query when you write `cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()`. Is `cls` a `Permission`? Are you sure this is all the query? Because it does not seem to be properly compiled and seems like you are having something else in this query as well.

Comment: I updated the question and included the query in the code snippet. `cls` is a `Role`. I cannot see any other part where data could get queried.